# Screen artifacts and keyboard not working with Tails on Lenovo yoga laptop

Tags: lenovo-laptop, tails

[image]

Laptop - Lenovo Yoga Slim 7i Pro

I am experiencing this grey dead screen at that same height every time. Screen returns to normal if I don't move the mouse (touchpad) for some time. When I use the touchpad screen tears up like in the image and another small screen starts glitching in and out at the bottom left. I can still interact with the OS with touchpad ignoring the artifacts. Keyboard does not work at all.

Comment: If it does this with Tails but not with a normal OS then the problem is Tails no0t having proper support for your hardware.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Windows is working fine. I was hoping if I could add or disable some flag while booting tails would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Tails is an older security OS.

I downloaded the Tail ISO and installed it into VMware Workstation V17.

It installs, there are no video artifacts, but there are no VMware Tools for it so it is not full screen.

It is not compatible with your laptop hardware and it will not install bare metal on your newer laptop. You will need a different operating system.

I spent some time with Tails. I am not impressed. If you want a penetration and forensics OS that supports torrents, consider Kali. I am using Kali 2023.2 here.

Comment: As you mentioned Tails is more security focused while Kali is for penetration. I would say they are made to achieve different goals so comparing them would not be fair.

Comment: Tails will not work on your machine, and Kali can do what you need.